# Select sub query in function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to create an inline function (stored procedure not allowed, as it cannot be accessed by end users, multistatement function not allowed because of performance issues). I am struck up in a piece of code.

The code goes like this.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [CDC].[FN_CBR_COPERNICUS_DBO_AGMASTER_ANY] (
    @START_LSN BINARY (10)
    ,@END_LSN BINARY (10)
    ,@APPLNID SMALLINT
    )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
        SELECT (
                SELECT STUFF((
                            SELECT ', ' + CBR.CBRCA_COLUMNNANME
                            FROM CBRCOLAPPLN CBR
                            WHERE CBR.CBRCA_APPLICATIONID = 1
                                AND CBR.CBRCA_TABLENAME = 'COPERNICUS_CORE_PARAMETER'
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                                ,TYPE
                            ).VALUE('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ' ') CHANGED_COLUMNS
                )
            ,__$OPERATION AS CBR_OPERATION
        FROM CBR.FN_CBR_GET_NET_CHANGES_ES_CMS_DBO_COPERNICUS_CORE_PARAMETER(0x0009631C000016F90029, 0x0009631D000008720001, 'ALL WITH MASK') AS CBRUPDATEDCOLUMNS
        )
```

The subquery select will return values , if I execute the subquery alone, it returns the below

```
 CMS_ID
,CMS_PARA_NAME
,CMS_PARA_TYPE
,CMS_PARA_MODULE
,CMS_PARA_VALUE
,CMS_COMMENTS
,CMS_ACTIVE_YN
```

When I place the values of subquery inside the function and place the code as

```
SELECT CMS_ID
    ,CMS_PARA_NAME
    ,CMS_PARA_TYPE
    ,CMS_PARA_MODULE
    ,CMS_PARA_VALUE
    ,CMS_COMMENTS
    ,CMS_ACTIVE_YN
    ,__$operation AS CBR_OPERATION
FROM CBR.FN_CBR_GET_NET_CHANGES_ES_CMS_DBO_COPERNICUS_CORE_PARAMETER(0x0009631C000016F90029, 0x0009631D000008720001, 'all with mask') AS CBRUPDATEDCOLUMNS
```

Upon executing it , I get the desired results,from the function `CBR.FN_CBR_GET_NET_CHANGES_ES_CMS_DBO_COPERNICUS_CORE_PARAMETER`

Whereas if I execute the first set of code (the one written in function), placed in the begining of the question, it just results me the value of the subquery * number of rows in the function
. It just gives me the result as below, along with the some ,__$OPERATION  value

```
CMS_ID, CMS_PARA_NAME, CMS_PARA_TYPE, CMS_PARA_MODULE, CMS_PARA_VALUE, CMS_COMMENTS, CMS_ACTIVE_YN
CMS_ID, CMS_PARA_NAME, CMS_PARA_TYPE, CMS_PARA_MODULE, CMS_PARA_VALUE, CMS_COMMENTS, CMS_ACTIVE_YN
CMS_ID, CMS_PARA_NAME, CMS_PARA_TYPE, CMS_PARA_MODULE, CMS_PARA_VALUE, CMS_COMMENTS, CMS_ACTIVE_YN
CMS_ID, CMS_PARA_NAME, CMS_PARA_TYPE, CMS_PARA_MODULE, CMS_PARA_VALUE, CMS_COMMENTS, CMS_ACTIVE_YN
```

Could you please help me where am I going wrong?

Comment: In your function, you are taking in multiple parameters (`@START_LSN` ,`@END_LSN`,`@APPLNID`), but don't see them being passed anywhere in the query within your function.

Comment: Sounds like the function is doing what it's coded to do.   What were you expecting it to do?